# Why does my print function print garbled message?

Tags: processing

Why does my print function print garbled message?

[image: Processing editor showing garbled print message]

Comment: This seems very strange, I am trying to replicate it but I can't . Could you go through what you did to get the result? Did you do anything to the Processing IDE? I see that you're in debug mode, although I don't see why that might cause problems, try turning the off maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is normal for `println();` to do but either way i think `print();` should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

try redownloading the processing ide.